# Are feature request questions on this site downvoted for being poor ideas?

Tags: discussion

On many sites, a well written question, even one asking about a possibly bad idea, is often upvoted. I've noticed a little difference on this site. Do people down vote questions because they do not contain a good idea, rather than giving a detailed answer explaining why it isn't the greatest idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People do both actually.

If there's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), votes will often represent whether people *want* that feature, or think it is a good idea to have it.

People might also leave answers with feedback about it, which will be voted based on peoples' agreement usually. We could have an answer that's heavily upvoted that says "No this sucks" (and explains why), as well as a question that's downvoted.